# Yoman generator retrieving module.js file in the last

Tags: angularjs, gulp, bower

I am using yoman generator to develop an angular js app .
when I add  new controller it is not rendering that controller .
It's generating an error controller is not registered .
After seeing at the source .There is a problem in rendering of module.js file 
,It's rendering in the last ie(module.js file is rendring after controller.js file ) .

Please help me to fix the error here is the images with error [image: ths is the image with erro discription]

Answer (score 0):

I got it , Just  delete all the content on ser .tmp\serve\index.html

now run  npm gulp

it work for me